# How to change BackColor of Tab?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two windows forms. 1st one is mdiParent form named as main. 2nd one is presentation form which is the child form of main form. presentaion form has a tabbed layout. presentation form has a preferences button. when I click on preferences button a new form('prefs') opens asking to click on a set color button. clicking that button opens a dialogResult to change color. when I select a color, the prefs backcolor changes. but dows not changes the tabbed layout('presentation form') backcolor. I'm building this application in  n-tier architecture. so help me how can I change the backcolor of a tab. I will upload code if you didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabControls do not have a BackColor property exposed since they typically draw based on the current window system theme.

It's usually not worth the effort, but the TabControl does has a DrawMode property where you would draw the tab yourself in the DrawItem event.

Each individual TabPage control does have a BackColor property available.

Answer (score 0):

here's my custom event handler I have to create a colored box that surrounds the text. The selected tab is one color and unselected is another...

```
private void ChangeTabColor(Object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Font TabFont;
    Brush BackBrush;// = new SolidBrush(Color.Green); //Set background color
    Brush ForeBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);//Set foreground color
    Brush borderBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);//Set foreground color

    if (e.Index == this.tabMain.SelectedIndex)
    {
        TabFont = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        BackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.MediumSeaGreen); //Set background color
        //ForeBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);//Set foreground color
    }
    else
    {
        TabFont = e.Font;
        BackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightSteelBlue); //Set background color
        //ForeBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);//Set foreground color
    }

    string TabName = this.tabMain.TabPages[e.Index].Text;
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    Rectangle r = e.Bounds;

    r = new Rectangle(r.X, r.Y + 5, r.Width, r.Height - 3);

    if (e.Index == this.tabMain.SelectedIndex)
    {
        Pen rectPen = new Pen(borderBrush, 1.0f);
        r.Y -= 2;
        r.X += 3;
        r.Height -= 9;
        r.Width -= 8;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackBrush, r);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TabName, TabFont, ForeBrush, r, sf);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(rectPen, r);
    }
    else
    {
        Pen rectPen = new Pen(borderBrush, 1.0f);
        r.Y -= 2;
        r.Height -= 4;
        r.Width -= 2;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackBrush, r);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TabName, TabFont, ForeBrush, r, sf);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(rectPen, r);
    }
    //Dispose objects
    sf.Dispose();

    if (e.Index == this.tabMain.SelectedIndex)
    {
        TabFont.Dispose();
        BackBrush.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        BackBrush.Dispose();
        ForeBrush.Dispose();
    }
}
```

of course "tabMain" refers to the tab control name. I hope this helps with what you are trying to do...probably a bit fancier, but the code isn't that difficult, and I think it looks a bit cleaner...plus in order to do this i made sure to set the approprate properties for font and item size:

Font = Arial, 9pt, style=Bold

ItemSize = 95, 25 
...the height is the important part, as long as you set SizeMode = Normal